# How to import custom made C++ data-types into C# application via DLL

Tags: c#, c++, dll, interop, custom-data-type

I have a C# Winforms application and already written C++ application. Long story short, I want my C# application to call different methods from the C++ dll, however, the C++ functions require non-primitive type parameters and my C# application does not *'support'* these parameters.

For example,

```
public:
       void demoFunction(DemoType param1, TypeDemo param2);
```

The *DemoType* and *TypeDemo* exist in the C++ application.

So in my C# application, how do I call this function exactly? Is there any way where I can tell my C# application to recognize these types?

I know that I can import a function from the dll:

```
[DllImport("Demo.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void demoFunction(?, ?);
```

The '?' signs in the code snippet is what I have trouble getting.

I am thinking that  if I managed to import these data types into my C# application, I would be able to cast the values when I am calling the function. Like: `(DemoType)value` where *value* is of type int.

And I cannot change the type of the parameters, they have to stay that way. Is that possible?

Thanks for all help in advance.

Comment: [DllImport] is suitable for a C language interface, it can't create C++ objects.  Only a C++ compiler knows how to do that.  If you can't modify the existing api then you need a C++/CLI project.

Comment: Perhaps you can wrap the C++ library with [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/CSharp.html) first?

Comment: But what are your custom types? Simple structs or classes?

Comment: @AndreaRossini There are both, so as far as I know now, I need to declare the structs and the classes above my 'DllImport' statement and give it the same properties. Doesn't sound very efficient though.